# Updating a table with data inserted in a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the code below for updating data from both textbox and listbox into two related tables. Unfortunately it brings an error. What might I be doing wrong?

```
    Db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblinvoice(InvoiceID,InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,CustomerID,SalesmanID,Remarks) VALUES('" & txtInvoiceID.Value & "','" & txtInvoiceNo.Value & "','" & txtInvoiceDate.Value & "','" & txtCustomerID.Value & "','" & txtSalesManID.Value & "','" & txtRemark.Value & "')"
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
If txtSalesManID.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Retrieve Sales Man ID.", vbInformation, "Choose SalesMan"
txtSalesManID.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
  For i = 0 To listBox1.ListCount - 1 Step 1
      Db.Execute "INSERT INTO InvoiceJoin(InvoiceID,ProductID,Propagator,GreenhouseNr,Qty)  VALUES('" & txtInvoiceID & "', " & listBox1.Column(1, i) & " , " & listBox1.Column(3, i) & " , " & listBox1.Column(4, i) & " , " & listBox1.Column(5, i) & ")"
        Next
        For i = 0 To listBox1.ListCount - 1 Step 1
       Db.Execute "Update tblTempStocks set Qty=Qty - " & listBox1.Column(4, i) & "  where ProductID=" & listBox1.Column(0, i) & ""
        Next
        MsgBox "Successfully done", vbInformation, "Sales"
End Sub
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Runtime error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually unnecessary and bad design. Calculate stock balance from raw transaction data when needed. Parameter delimiters may be wrong in SQL statements. Use apostrophe for text type, # for data/time, nothing for number. Make sure txtSalesManID.Value could be empty string and not actually Null.